# samsung s4 camera effects show in preview but not in picture

Tags: android, camera, samsung-mobile

I have an interesting bug in my camera application.
When the user selects a color effect to use the preview window shows the desired effect but the actual picture taken is sans (without) effect...

A bit of code:

```
backCameraParams.setColorEffect("mono");
mCamera.setParameters(backCameraParams);
```

Please note that this "feature" has only been reproduced on the Samsung galaxy S4 GT-19500

Any help would be greatly appreciated.