# Android camera API: getSupportedColorEffects can return unsupported effects?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I just faced the strange problem. My app crashes with

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Camera.java)
```

despite the fact, that effect I tried to set is listed in `parameters.getSupportedColorEffects()`.

Did anyone faced the similar problem? I suppose it device-specific bug, because I can reproduce it only on Samsung Galaxy S4 (and I got Crashlytics reports only from this device). The effects are `blackboard` and `whiteboard`

EDIT: some code added, but it's not very necessary, I described the whole issue in post.

```
public void setColorEffect(String colorEffect)
{
    if (mCamera != null)
    {
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(colorEffect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
}
```

This method is called only on popupWindow item click, which contains only values from `getSupportedColorEffects`:

```
final List<String> colorEffects = mPreview.getSupportedColorEffects();
if (colorEffects != null)
{
    final CustomPopUpAdapter adapter = new CustomPopUpAdapter(this, colorEffects.toArray(new String[colorEffectsSize]));
    adapter.setSelectedItem(items[savedColorEffect]);
    final ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this);
    // ...
    popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            mPreview.setColorEffect(colorEffects.get(position));
            savedColorEffect = position;
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupWindow.show();
}
```

Comment: post relevant code here so we giving you best solution without code we Can't ?

Comment: is `params` null or more importantly, support `setColorEffect`?

Comment: `params` not null, the list contains 15 items on tested device, and app crashes only on 2 of them.

Comment: But are you sure about the parameter used in setColorEffect ?
The list come from the supported effects so it should be correct but print it just in case.
EDIT : Which one gave an exception ?

Comment: @AxelH, I'm 100% sure about the parameter, I even checked it in debug mode. The effect is listed in getSupportedColorEffects, but the app crashes with `setParameters failed`.

Comment: @AxelH, I already mentioned concrete color effects in post - `blackboard` and `whiteboard`

Comment: @IvanGoncharov Sorry, didn't read these lines because of the Samsung brand :p look at this "solution" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254082/setparameters-failed-when-setting-sepia-but-zoom-works-fine

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @AxelH! Specifically, I would start by trying to stop preview before switching color effect.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention, @AlexCohn! That's the first thing I tried after reading your answer, but unfortunately it didn't help. I've also tried some 'dumb' solution like catching the exception, but it looks ugly - the preview freezes on several seconds, like it happens on crash, and later camera became broken and effect switching is not working at all.

Comment: I wonder if any color effects work on your device. Note that there is an (unlikely) possibility that **mPreview.getSupportedColorEffects()** returns color effects supported for the back-facing camera, but fails to set this for front-facing camera.

Comment: If you have access to a physical device, open the stock camera app and check which color effects it presents. Also I find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173115/samsung-s4-camera-effects-show-in-preview-but-not-in-picture.

Comment: If everything else fails, you may be forced to use the [Samsung Camera SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#camera).

Comment: Simple effects like sepia/negative/mono works well.
Your assumption was right, I also thought about it. These effects doesn't fail on back-facing camera! (They're seems does nothing, but at least not crashes the application). Yesterday I only checked if the right camera was initialized, when I get the list of supported effects.